# WordPress: How to get all sub categories id and add the parent category's ID to the new array?

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

I want to get all the sub categories' ID and add all the sub cat IDs and the parent ID to a new array.

For example:

```
Parent $ID=1
  sub cat 1 :11
  sub cat 2 :12
  sub cat 3 :13
  sub cat 4 :14
$arr = array(11,12,13,14)
```

The result:

```
$arr2 = array(1,11,12,13,14) // add parent ID to the array.

$categories=get_categories($ID);
```

Answer (score 2):

1.) `get_all_category_ids()` will retrive all the category IDS. it returns an  array containing both the child and parent category ID'es.

2.) If you want to get it for a particular category: (Note: it will include all the child/child*n as well)

```
 //$pid = parent category id
$Result = array_merge(array_diff(explode('/',get_category_children($pid)),array("")),array($pid));
```

3.) if you want only the immediate child categories: ie: parent/child and not parent/child/child*n

```
            //$pid = parent category id;         
            $child_cats=array();

            foreach(get_all_category_ids() as $cat)
            {
                if(get_category($cat)->parent==$pid)
                {
                    $child_cats[]=$cat;
                }
            }

            $result = array_merge($child_cats,array($pid));
```